# Python: How to use print without converting to ASCII

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, formatting

I have a mixture of hex and some numbers, I want to print:

> "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9b\x00\x00\x00\xebS\xc3\x90\x08\x00\x00\x00\xed\x9b\xbcX\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x820416e9c05a9942f67d1ee0b53642e79fae45af47a3afceb6a21a94c8487e1290645d789253fb05a1a8ee529b2cb4de2877fbbe11aa24a64dc20450ff722e41f92d\xed\x18\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"

When I print, it converts it to ASCII, how do I keep the format including the slash signs. I tried

> ' '.join(hex(ord(i)) for i in binascii.unhexlify('deadbeef'))

But it ends up removing the backslash or if I tried adding it, it would add to the ones in the middle. I just want to print exactly this, I can do this in C, why is it so difficult in Python!

Comment: If it's a consist string, you can just declare it as raw string with a `r` prefix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use **[raw string](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)** `r'hello world'`

```
x = r"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9b\x00\x00\x00\xebS\xc3\x90\x08\x00\x00\x00\xed\x9b\xbcX\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x820416e9c05a9942f67d1ee0b53642e79fae45af47a3afceb6a21a94c8487e1290645d789253fb05a1a8ee529b2cb4de2877fbbe11aa24a64dc20450ff722e41f92d\xed\x18\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"`
print(x)
```

Comment: thanks, this led me to the right answer. string_raw=string.encode('string-escape')

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to get the functionality you want is to use raw string literals (see the [String Literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) documentation)

In short, prepend the string declaration with either r or R:

```
>>> str = r"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9b\x00\x00\x00\xebS\xc3\x90\x08\x00\x00\x00\xed\x9b\xbcX\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x820416e9c05a9942f67d1ee0b53642e79fae45af47a3afceb6a21a94c8487e1290645d789253fb05a1a8ee529b2cb4de2877fbbe11aa24a64dc20450ff722e41f92d\xed\x18\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
>>> print str
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9b\x00\x00\x00\xebS\xc3\x90\x08\x00\x00\x00\xed\x9b\xbcX\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x820416e9c05a9942f67d1ee0b53642e79fae45af47a3afceb6a21a94c8487e1290645d789253fb05a1a8ee529b2cb4de2877fbbe11aa24a64dc20450ff722e41f92d\xed\x18\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```